# I am trying to run test script using genymotion but Appium throwing some error

Tags: selenium, appium, genymotion

***plz help me***

****This is my code****

```
public class demo1 {
    public WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void test() throws MalformedURLException
    {


        String apkpath=("C:\\App\\bookmyshow.apk");
        File app=new File(apkpath);

        final DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4.4");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 API 19 - 1080x1920");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.bookmyshow.apk"); 
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "bookmyshow.apk");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

}
```

================================================================================

**Appium Error**

========================================================================

> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --app C:\App\bookmyshow.apk --no-reset --avd-args 192.168.71.101:5555 --platform-name Android --platform-version 19 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
>   info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"C:\App\bookmyshow.apk","address":"127.0.0.1","noReset":true,"logNoColors":true,"avdArgs":"192.168.71.101:5555","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"19","automationName":"Appium"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\App\bookmyshow.apk","appPackage":"com.bookmyshow.apk","appActivity":"bookmyshow.apk","platformVersion":"4.4.4","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 API 19 - 1080x1920"},"requiredCapabilities":{}},"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\App\bookmyshow.apk","appPackage":"com.bookmyshow.apk","appActivity":"bookmyshow.apk","platformVersion":"4.4.4","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 API 19 - 1080x1920"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_112)
>   info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: C:\App\bookmyshow.apk
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 25722b10-f229-42af-a64c-347ebbe9c25f
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_112
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? false
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 2 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device 192.168.71.101:5555
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to 192.168.71.101:5555
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.71.101:5555 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.71.101:5555 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.71.101:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
>   info: Device API level is: 19
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.71.101:5555 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
>   info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: en
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\App\bookmyshow.apk" "C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Temp\com.bookmyshow.apk" en
>   info: [debug] No strings.xml for language 'en', getting default strings.xml
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\App\bookmyshow.apk" "C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Temp\com.bookmyshow.apk"
>   warn: Error getting strings.xml from apk
>   info: [debug] Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Could not load resources.arsc from file: C:\App\bookmyshow.apk
>     at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:608)
>     at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:74)
>     at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:66)
>     at io.appium.apktools.StringsXML.run(StringsXML.java:84)
>     at io.appium.apktools.Main.main(Main.java:31)
>   Caused by: brut.directory.DirectoryException: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
>     at brut.directory.ZipRODirectory.(ZipRODirectory.java:54)
>     at brut.directory.ZipRODirectory.(ZipRODirectory.java:37)
>     at brut.androlib.res.util.ExtFile.getDirectory(ExtFile.java:55)
>     at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:605)
>     ... 4 more
>   Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
>     at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory32(ZipFile.java:717)
>     at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:672)
>     at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:406)
>     at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:206)
>     at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:182)
>     at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:143)
>     at brut.directory.ZipExtFile.(ZipExtFile.java:28)
>     at brut.directory.ZipRODirectory.(ZipRODirectory.java:52)
>     ... 7 more
>
> warn: Could not get strings, continuing anyway
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.71.101:5555 shell "echo '{}' > /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.2\aapt.exe dump xmltree C:\App\bookmyshow.apk AndroidManifest.xml
>   warn: W/zipro   ( 6068): Error opening archive C:\App\bookmyshow.apk: Invalid file
>   ERROR: dump failed because resource AndroidManifest.xml found
>
> info: [debug] Set app process to: com.bookmyshow.apk
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\App\bookmyshow.apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\App\bookmyshow.apk
>   info: [debug] App not signed with debug cert.
>   info: [debug] Resigning apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\sign.jar" C:\App\bookmyshow.apk --override
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   warn: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\sign.jar" C:\App\bookmyshow.apk --override"
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)
>     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:166)
>     at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:145)
>     at s.Sign.sign(Sign.java:441)
>     at s.Sign.main(Sign.java:532)
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"java -jar \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\sign.jar\" C:\App\bookmyshow.apk --override\"\njava.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file\r\n\tat java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)\r\n\tat java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)\r\n\tat java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:166)\r\n\tat java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:145)\r\n\tat s.Sign.sign(Sign.java:441)\r\n\tat s.Sign.main(Sign.java:532)\r\n)","killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null,"cmd":"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"java -jar \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\sign.jar\" C:\App\bookmyshow.apk --override\"","origValue":"Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"java -jar \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\sign.jar\" C:\App\bookmyshow.apk --override\"\njava.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file\r\n\tat java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)\r\n\tat java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)\r\n\tat java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:166)\r\n\tat java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:145)\r\n\tat s.Sign.sign(Sign.java:441)\r\n\tat s.Sign.main(Sign.java:532)\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 11155.864 ms - 1554

=========================================================================

** img**
[Android Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlQe0.png)

================================================================

## **CMD: adb devices**

C:\Users\Santo>C:\Users\Santo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
List of devices attached
192.168.71.101:5555     device

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the desired capabilities under @Test. Create a separate setUp() function to set the desired capabilities and that function needs to be annotated as @Before.